# KeyError: "DatetimeIndex(['2006-12-31', '2007-12-31'],\n dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None) not in index

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, datavisualization.toolkit

I am visualizing my data in bar, column, line and scatter chart using matplotlib for the first time. I am getting an error whenever I am mentioning the x and y axis. Here is my code below for all charts,

```
df.plot.bar(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']), y=df[value])
df.plot.bar(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']), y=df[value])
df.plot.line(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']), y=df[value])
df.plot.scatter(x=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']), y=df[value])
plt.show()
```

I have found similar issue in [datetime index KeyError: 'the label [2000-01-03 00:00:00] is not in the [index]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863481/datetime-index-keyerror-the-label-2000-01-03-000000-is-not-in-the-index). But it is not solving my problem.

Comment: You're not meant to give the complete data to the `x` and `y` arguments, but the names of the columns you want to use. Else you might want to use matplotlib directly, `plt.plot()` or `plt.bar()`

Comment: Thanks, I know it. But I need to mention it for more uses in future. I mean my x axis will always refer date column, but y-axis will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake what I did. I need to define the x and y axis by the column name without mentioning like **df['date']**. However, I have visualized the scatter plot using **scatter_matrix**. So the workable code is,

```
df.plot.bar(pd.DatetimeIndex(x='date', y='value')
df.plot.bar(pd.DatetimeIndex(x='date', y='value')
df.plot.line(pd.DatetimeIndex(x='date', y='value')
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
plt.show()
```